# React-admin exclude fields when sending PATCH requests

Tags: react-admin

I am using react-admin to display my data in a simple admin panel. I have a “timeAdded” field that I want to display in the `<List>` but I don’t want it sent in the payload when I `<Edit>` (My api does not accept patch requests that try and patch the “timeAdded” field).

Is there any way to remove the fields/params I don’t want sent in the payload when using the `<Edit>` component?

(I can share code if needed)

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you have to change the data before sending it, in your dataProvider. The [dataProvider documentation](https://marmelab.com/react-admin/DataProviders.html#extending-a-data-provider-example-of-file-upload) shows how to do that:

```js
import simpleRestProvider from 'ra-data-simple-rest';

const dataProvider = simpleRestProvider('http://path.to.my.api/');

const myDataProvider = {
    ...dataProvider,
    update: (resource, params) => {
        if (resource !== 'posts' || !params.data.pictures) {
            // fallback to the default implementation
            return dataProvider.update(resource, params);
        }
        /**
         * For posts update only, remove timeAdded field
         */
        const { data: { timeAdded, ...restData }, ...rest } = params;
        return dataProvider.update(resource, { data: restData, ...rest });
    }),
};
```

Answer (score 1):

If modifying the data provider is not possible or harder than the documentation example, I would also recommend checking out the `transform` feature.

It is described here : https://marmelab.com/react-admin/CreateEdit.html#transform and an example is given here:https://marmelab.com/react-admin/CreateEdit.html#altering-the-form-values-before-submitting

It could look something like this:

```js
export const WhatEver = (props) => {
    const transform = (data) => {
        if(data.timeAdded) {
            delete data.timeAdded;
        }
        return data
    };
    return (
        <Edit {...props} transform={transform} >
            ...
        </Edit>
    );
}
```